# Efficiently counting total number of results in a complicated MySQL query ignoring LIMIT

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a slightly complex SQL Query (shown below). This lists all rows of `table_p` with some example filters applied (in the e.g. below, showing only rows which have rows of `table_x` reference it):

I'm trying to find a way to efficiently get the number of total results past the LIMIT query. I've tried two options:

- Using `MYSQL_CALC_ROWS p.id` - The result of this greatly increased the time taken to perform it.
- Using a sub query, selecting only `x_count` (for filters) and wrapping it in a `COUNT(0) FROM ...` parent query. This results in the count query being incredibly slow too (but only slightly faster than the former).

The second option seems the worst in my testing, as the first query can perform very fast until certain filters start getting applied, then it becomes slow anyway. having a second query would really badly hurt speed times.

In this situation, I can only think of using `MYSQL_CALC_ROWS` as a viable option, but I'm wondering if there's a method I haven't seen or tried yet to improve the efficiency of such a query.

The monster:

```
SELECT 
    p.`id`,
    -- Demonstrating usage of two joins to the same table.
    u.`name`,
    u2.`name` AS name2,
    COUNT(x.`id`) AS x_count,

-- p has 0 - 1 of u
-- p has 0 - 1 of u2
-- p has 0 - * of x

FROM 
    `table_p` AS `p` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `table_u` AS `u` 
ON 
    p.`u_id` = u.`id` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `table_u` AS `u2` 
ON 
    p.`u2_id` = u2.`id` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `table_x` AS `x` 
ON 
    p.`id` = x.`p_id` 

WHERE 
    x.`some_column` != 'Some Value' 
AND 
    p.`another_column` <> 'Another Value' 

GROUP BY 
    p.`package_id` 

HAVING
    `x_count` > 0

ORDER BY 
    p.id DESC 

-- Second page, showing 20 results

LIMIT 20, 20`
```

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated. I'm building for a system with tens of thousands of rows minimum, so processing time is exponential!

Comment: Optimize MySQL's settings first. Tens of thousands of rows is nothing, even tens of millions is nothing if you're using InnoDB and large enough `innodb_buffer_pool`. As for what's the fastest - analyse the query with EXPLAIN first, to make it run faster. Using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *should* suffice your needs though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working locally and using a cms to help debug / analyse the queries. The largest area seems to be involving a temporary table. Unfortunately, dev steps past local are out of my control. The staging and production server have pretty tight restrictions, but I can see if it's possible to modify those kinds of settings. Thanks for giving me a suitable place to start!

Comment: Production server(s), should implement these optimization steps (they always do, no one likes their site loading for a few minutes). If nothing helps, it's out of your control thus you shouldn't beat yourself over it. Good luck with the project :)